# how to display 2d array in blade template sent from controller to view

Tags: php, laravel-5

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => piya
            [1] => piya@gmail.com
            [2] => smting
            [3] => 1234567890
            [4] => gnfvjn
            [5] => 210
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => dash
            [1] => dash@gmail.com
            [2] => smting
            [3] => 3213243547
            [4] => gnfvjn
            [5] => 211
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => dash
            [1] => dash@gmail.com
            [2] => smting
            [3] => 3213243547
            [4] => gnfvjn
            [5] => 212
        )
)
```

How to display this array structure ?
I keep getting "trying to get property of non-object" error.

Comment: can you show code in your blade file..??

Comment: Do you want to get the values of array and display them to the blade template?

Comment: i want to display it in a table format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since it is 2 dim. array, first foreach outputs 2nd array(Ex: ['el1','el2'....]). Then 2nd foreach outputs string elements(Ex: 'el1', 'el2')

```
@foreach($array as $array2)
 @foreach($array2 as $value)
  {!! $value !!}
 @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Since it is 2 dim. array, first foreach outputs 2nd array(Ex: ['el1','el2'....]). Then 2nd foreach outputs string elements(Ex: 'el1', 'el2')

Comment: still gives "Trying to get property of non-object" error